# Auto Generate Column from Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Lets say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_mg_accounts (
    account_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,L,
    holder_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (holder_id) REFERENCES tbl_mg_holders(holder_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I want to add another column that auto-fills but it's based on a column within the foreign table reference.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_mg_accounts (
    account_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,L,
    holder_id INT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    test_col VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS CONCAT(tbl_mg_holders.holder_name, username) VIRTUAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (holder_id) REFERENCES tbl_mg_holders(holder_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This is giving me an error...
Perhaps the addition of below is a syntax issue or is this actually a limitation with MySQL/MariaDB?

```
test_col VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS CONCAT(tbl_mg_holders.holder_name, username) VIRTUAL
```

Comment: It's a limitation see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok Yes this seems like a limitation.

I've instead created a `VIEW` for my requirements and let the backend process this way.